# Jquery search not hiding first row in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I am having difficulty in understanding as to why my search of a table column is always showing the first row and the matched row after that? Even though the keyword doesn't match the cell in row 1 it will always show on top? I have gone through my code several times and tried different approach it still wont hide the first row?

Here is my working code

```
$('#filterbyname').on("keyup", function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var matches = $("table.bill tr:not(:first-of-type)");

        matches.each(function (i,e) {            
            debugger;
            $row = $(this);                
            $cells = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)");

            $cells.each(function (i2, e2) {
                var cell = $(this).text();
                debugger;
                $row.toggle(cell.indexOf(val) >= 0);             
            });
        });
 });
```

You can see from the above code if `cell.indexOf(val) >= 0)` then it will toggle according the matching rows.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: It's due to `tr:not(:first-of-type)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact in your `matches` variables you are using `tr:not(:first-of-type)` which selects all the rows expect the first one, because `:not` selector excludes all elements that matches `:first-of-type` here, which means that they are not the first child in their parent, so the first `tr` will be ignored.

Change this code:

```
var matches = $("table.bill tr:not(:first-of-type)");
```

To the following:

```
var matches = $("table.bill tr");
```

Comment: If `:not(:first-of-type)` is there to get rid of a header, then use `$("table.bill > tbody > tr")`

Comment: @freedomn-m There are no sign that there's a ` thead` with a `tr` in the OP.

Comment: @chsdk thanks for that it worked a treat. As freedomn-m pointed out above it was there to get rid of header.

Comment: @chsdk correct, hence the "**if** this is the case".  The comment was directed at OP, not at this answer specifically (apologies that this wasn't clear).  It was there for a reason, and a guess would be that it was to ignore the first `tr` - ie the one in the header.  Where there wasn't a header, it would ignore the first row in the body.  Hence the suggestion.